# Concept needed for building consistent urls (routes)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, regex, vb.net

My project has the need to build consistent urls similar to the ones here on stackoverflow.  I know how I "can" do it by running the string through multiple filters, but I'm wondering if I can do it all with a single method.

Basically I want to remove all special characters, and replace them with dashes BUT if there are multiple dashes in a row, I need them to be a single dash. How can I implement this as clean as possible?

Example: If I were to use the following string.

> My #1 Event

**My** regex would create the following string

> my--1-event

notice how there are two dashes (one for the space and one for the "#" symbol). What I need is

> my-1-event

Here's how I'm implementing it currently

```
    ''# <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ToUrlFriendlyString(ByVal input As String) As String
        Dim reg As New Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9]")
        ''# I could run a loop filter here to match "--" and replace it with "-"
        ''# but that seems like more overhead than necessary.
        Return (reg.Replace(Trim(input), "-"))
    End Function
```

And then all I do is call the extension method

```
    Dim UrlFriendlyString = MyTile.ToUrlFriendlyString
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `+` to the end of the regex.
This will tell it to match one or more characters that match the character class that precedes the `+`.

Also, you should create your `Regex` instance in a `Shared` field outside the method so that .Net won't need to parse the regex again every time you call the method.

#### [edited by rockinthesixstring]: here's the final result

```
    Private UrlRegex As Regex = New Regex("[^a-z0-9]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ToUrlFriendlyString(ByVal input As String) As String
        Return (UrlRegex.Replace(Trim(input), "-"))
    End Function
```

Comment: holy crap, could that be any more simple??? `Dim reg As New Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9]+")`

Comment: @rock: Yes, it could.  `, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Comment: does it have to be "shared" or can it just be "private"?  Sorry I don't know how some of this stuff works yet.

Comment: what would using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` gain in this situation?

Comment: @rock: It should certainly be `Private`.  `Shared` is not an access modifier; it means that there will be one instance globally, not one per class.  (`static` in C#)

Comment: @rock: It would let you get rid of `A-Z`.

Comment: "Variables in Modules cannot be declared as Shared"

Comment: @rock: I forgot about that.  All members defined in Modules are implicitly `Shared`; you don't need to (and cannot) add the `Shared` keyword yourself.  (I haven't done VB in a while; the C# equivalent, a `static class`, requires the `static` keyword for every member)

Answer (score 0):

Another way I do this without using a regex and also is a little simpler to understand is the following:

Excuse me on my vb as I am mainly C# guy.

```
''# <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>    
Public Function ToUrlFriendlyString(ByVal input As String) As String
    If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(s) = True Then
        Return [String].Empty
    End If    

    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    Dim slug = input.Trim().ToLowerInvariant()

    For Each c As Char in slug
        Select Case c
            Case ' '
                builder.Append("-")
            Case '&'
                builder.Append("and")
            Case Else
                If (c >= '0' And c <= '9') OrElse (c >= 'a' And c <= 'z') And c != '-')
                    builder.Append(c)
                End If
        End Select
    Next

    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: That's quite a bit bigger of a function. Have you seen any performance trade off doing it this way over the regex way?